# Determine background img heigth with px

Tags: css

I have an image named "button.png", which has a width of 167px, and a height of 90px.

I need to create a CSS class using "button.png" as a background, but only showing from the top of the image to the `45px` "middle" mark.

I also want to make it so that when this class is hovered, it shows the image from the `45px` "middle" mark, to the bottom.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clip the background to the content box and adjust padding to control the visible part of it:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border:2px solid;
  padding-bottom:50px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/0/200/100);
  background-clip:content-box;
  
  cursor:pointer;
  transition:1s all;
}
.box:hover {
   padding-bottom:0;
   padding-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Or simple adjust the `background-position` if you want your image to cover the button:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  border:2px solid;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/0/200/100);
  background-position:top;
  
  cursor:pointer;
  transition:1s all;
}
.box:hover {;
  background-position:bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```